# Как в Javascript определить недоступность картинки?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как в Javascript определить недоступность картинки? Может, это возможно, например, на jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте отправить HEAD запрос к URL картинки. Он не будет загружать непосредственно картинку, а вернёт вам только HTTP статус и хедеры ответа. По HTTP статусу легко определить доступность картинки. На jQuery это будет выглядеть так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'image.jpg',
    complete: function(data) {
        if (data.status !== 200) {
            // картника недоступна
        }
    }
});
```

Также стоит обрабатывать [статусы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP), начинающиеся на 3xx.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько актуально сейчас так использовать: есть метод onerror, и если картинки нет по указанному адресу, он выполняет определённые действия, например, [подставляет другую картинку](http://jsfiddle.net/k0m3r9Ly/).